# Why does backup requires root?

Tags: titanium-backup

Titanium backup and helium backup requires root

I saw http://www.syncios.com/version-compare.html that doesn't seem to require root and cost $19. I have never heard of the software anywhere else and not sure what's the difference between that and titanium backup.

Why?

What does rooting have anything to do with backing up?

Comment: You can also create a backup by using adb. `adb backup`.

Comment: Have you tried Helium Backup? It asks for root but it doesn't depend upon it. It can take backups of certain apps without root but then you need to have a PC in proximity because that is the non-root alternative it provides.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like that software doesn't back up apps or data, it just copies off what is in your internal SD storage (the general file storage area for pictures, downloads, etc.).

Backing up apps and their data requires root because apps and their data are protected from non-privileged users — primarily, other apps.  This prevents malware from accessing or damaging your private information.